# Assert that variable is defined

Tags: angular, typescript

I sometimes have to deal with objects defined like :

```
value: T | undefined
```

At some point in the code, I know that `value` cannot be `undefined` and I just want to get it as a `T`. For this purpose, I usually create this
 kind of method :

```
public static getDefinedValue<T>(value: T | undefined): T {
  if (value) {
    return value;
  } else {
    throw Error('Yolo')
  }
}
```

But I feel that my need is generic. Is there a built-in function or a more concise syntax that already does that ?

Comment: I know what you're saying, but to your credit, this solution seems nice a clear to me. The other option is just to use it's values if it exists, otherwise use a fallback (eg using tuples: const value = value ? value : fallback; or eg using fallback:  value || fallback. One thing to be aware of is that both my solution and yours above are not type safe as javascript infers 0, null, undefined, "" all to be falsey

Answer (score 0):

As you know that they are defined you can use `as` to type it directly. It's called **Type assertion**.

It would look like `(value as T)` and you would have it 'casted' to the type you want.

You can check it here how it works:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

If you still want to be sure that the value is not defined you can do a simple:

```
if (value)  { (values as T)....}
```